# can recursive SQL find spanning tree forest

Tags: sql-server

I have a table like this

```
create table #data (node int, linkA char(1), linkB char(2));
insert into #data
values
(1, 'a', 'aa'),
(2, 'b', 'aa'),
(3, 'a', 'xx'),
(4, 'c', 'yy'),
(5, 'b', 'zz'),
(6, 'd', 'yy')
--...,
--more than 100k rows
```

The objective is to group nodes that linked by either link type A or type B recursively. So in the example, 1 linked to 2 through type B, 2 further linked to 5 through type A; 1 also linked to 3; so they are all in one group.

I can solve this using two nested while loops like below, but the performance is terrible as you can imagine.

```
declare @grp int = 0
select top 0 @grp grp, * into #x from #data
select * into #result from #x

while exists(select * from #data)
begin

    insert into #x
    select top 1 @grp, * from #data;

    while @@ROWCOUNT > 0 
    begin

        insert into #x
        select @grp, * 
        from #data d
        where exists (
            select * from #x rec 
            where d.linkA = rec.linkA
            or d.linkB = rec.linkB
            ) 
            and not exists (select * from #x where #x.node = d.node)
    end

    insert into #result
    select * from #x;

    delete #data where node in (select node from #x);

    truncate table #x;

    set @grp += 1;
end

select * from #result
```

**Current and Desired Output:**

```
grp | node | linkA | linkB
0   | 1    | a     | aa
0   | 2    | b     | aa
0   | 3    | a     | xx
0   | 5    | b     | zz
1   | 4    | c     | yy
1   | 6    | d     | yy
```

I wonder if a recursive CTE can do it better, but I couldn't figure out. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: _"I wonder if a recursive CTE can do it better"_... yes it would. Can you add your desired output please as I don't understand what you mean with: _"The objective is to group nodes that linked by either link type A or type B recursively"_

Comment: The desired result is at the last statement, select * from #result

Comment: it's still better to show it in the question

Comment: sure, but any other sensible ways that can show different groups are also good.